# How to align brand and menu items in navbar?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have designed a menu bar using bootstrap navbar. Brand Image and menu items are not aligned. Brand is aligned to the top left and menu items in the middle.
when i minimize the windows, brand image and menu items displays in two rows.
How do i fix this?

Here is my navbar code:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="banner">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span
                        class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span
                        class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.jsp"><img src="../img/waytowealth_green1.png" alt="logo" /> </a>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right">
                <ul id="ulOptions" class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                    <li <c:out value="${param.page=='Home'?'class=active':''}"/> ><a href="index.jsp?page=Home">Home</a></li>
                    <li <c:out value="${param.page=='MutualFunds'?'class=active':''}"/>><a href="MutualFunds.jsp?page=MutualFunds">Mutual Funds</a></li>
                    <li <c:out value="${param.page=='FP'?'class=active':''}"/>><a href="FinancialPlanning.jsp?page=FP">Financial Planning</a></li>
                    <li <c:out value="${param.page=='Insurance'?'class=active':''}"/>><a href="Insurance.jsp?page=Insurance">Insurance</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown <c:out value="${param.page=='calculator'?'active':''}"/>"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"
                        data-toggle="dropdown">Calculators<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="m_sip.jsp?page=calculator">Monthly Systematic Investment
                                    Plan</a></li>
                            <li><a href="lumpsum_fv.jsp?page=calculator">One Time Investment
                                    Calculator</a></li>
                            <li><a href="m_sip_fv.jsp?page=calculator">Final Value of Monthly SIP
                                    Calculator</a></li>
                        </ul></li>
                    <li <c:out value="${param.page=='Downloads'?'class=active':''}"/>><a href="Downloads.jsp?page=Downloads">Downloads</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Downloads.jsp">Articles</a></li>
                    <li <c:out value="${param.page=='ContactUs'?'class=active':''}"/>><a href="ContactUs.jsp?page=ContactUs">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li <c:out value="${param.page=='AboutUs'?'class=active':''}"/>><a href="AboutUs.jsp?page=AboutUs">About Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--/.container-->
    </nav>
```

Comment: Can you setup a demo of the code? Dynamic code will not help us for finding the problem.